# How to modify HTML layout inside a View template

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am very new to Drupal and this is my first post in this community. What I am trying to achieve I know may be very simple but just don't know how! So I am looking forward for expert help.

First please see the screenshot:

[image]

**Below is what I want to achieve:**

1. WHITE boxes are laid out as float: left;
2. I want A, B and C to shift below their respective titles, i.e. at A1, B1 and C1 spots respectively.
3. I want to make the TITLE + A1 to be under the same container so the container can float left itself. Same with TITLE  + B1 and TITLE + C1

I copied **views-view-unformatted.tpl.php** file to my custom theme folder. The code snippet is rendering the data fine:

`<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

But I want each of the field in `$row` to be printed in a way I want, e.g.:

`<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <div class="image-class"><img src="" /></div>
    <div class="text-class">
      <?php print $row->title ?><br />
      <?php print $row->body ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

I believe there is a way to do it but don't know how. `$row->title` or `$row->body` is actually printing (rendering) nothing.

Also, if I modify **views-view-unformatted-tpl.php** it will affect the entire site. So I want a **separate view** for this purpose. How to do this?

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't use `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` because it will affect all unformatted views. What you need to do, is add your view name so it only affects that specific view. **views-view-unformatted--[view-name].tpl.php**

Comment: Yes, that's one of my questions as well. Thanks for your valuable comments. I will override default view with mine. But how should I proceed with the other part of my question - i.e. shifting content to different area, as I have marked in the screenshot. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**views-view-fields--[view-name]--[machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg).tpl.php**

Ex: `views-view-fields--hello-world--block-1.tpl.php`

```
<div class="picture">
  <?php print $fields["field_image"]->content; ?>
</div>

<div class="text-wrapper">

  <div class="title">
     <?php print $fields["title"]->content; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="small-summary">
     <?php print $fields["body-summary"]->content; // if you r using a body summary ?> 
     <?php // if you are using an actual field then use:  print $fields["field_name"]->content; ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.picture { float: left; }
```